# Найти и обосновать сказуемое в главном предложении.Что за форма "больше восьми"?

Tags: синтаксис

Больше восьми минут необходимо,чтобы солнечный свет дошёл до Земли.

Я предполагаю, что главное предложение безличное. Сказуемое: или необходимо (и тогда оставшаяся часть - (что?) дополнение?; (сколько?) обстоятельство?) или всё главное - это составное именное, т. к. в этом случае у сказуемого больше смысла появляется.
А что такое "больше восьми"...

Answer (score 1):

***Больше восьми минут необходимо,чтобы солнечный свет дошёл до Земли.***

Двусоставное предложение.

***Больше восьми минут*** — подлежащее, выражено неразложимым количественным оборотом. Другие варианты: около восьми, свыше восьми и т.д. Количественный оборот согласуется со сказуемым в ср. роде.

***Необходимо*** — именная часть сказуемого, выражена кратким прилагательным. Сравнить: это время необходимо, этот период времени необходим.

Comment: И-эх-эх! Честное слово, я очень рада, что Вы снова с нами!

Comment: Спасибо, Римма. Для меня тоже очень важно Ваше присутствие на этом форуме.